# Correlation with different vector length

Tags: r, expand

I asked a question regarding this earlier which was migrated to stats.stackexchange

After answers from there I had some questions regarding implementation in R to solve this and thought I should ask them here.

This is what I would like to produce:

I have two seperate colums, price and time, for each equity. If the time is present for equity X but not equity Y then the previous price should be put into the vector and vice versa.

Is a if loop the solution here? 
Thanks for your help.

As the following example:

```
X           Y   
price   time   price   time
10     540     20  540
11     541     21  541
12     542     22  543
13     544     23  544
14     545     24  545

price   time   price   time
10     540     20  540
11     541     21  541
12     542     21  542
12     543     22  543
13     544     23  544
14     545     24  545
```

Comment: You will need to make a correlation matrix in R.

Answer (score 5):

```
x <- read.table(text = "price   time
 10     540
 11     541
 12     542
 13     544
 14     545", header = TRUE);

 y <- read.table(text = "price   time
  20  540
  21  541
  22  543
  23  544
  24  545", header = TRUE)

 big <- merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "time")
 big
 #   time price.x price.y
 # 1  540      10      20
 # 2  541      11      21
 # 3  542      12      NA
 # 4  543      NA      22
 # 5  544      13      23
 # 6  545      14      24

library(zoo)
big$price.x <- na.locf(big$price.x)
big$price.y <- na.locf(big$price.y)
```

If the first value is an `NA` or even the second value and so on is an `NA` I think you want to then use the first non NA value for all the previous entries?

e.g.

```
NA,1,2,3,NA
# changed to
1,1,2,3,3
```

If so the this will work:

```
replaceKEEPFIRST <- function(x) {
x2    <- na.locf(x)
diffx <- length(x) - length(x2)
val   <- c(rep(x2[1],diffx),x2)
return(val)
}

myx <- c(NA,1,2,3,NA)
myy <- c(1,2,3,NA)
replaceKEEPFIRST(myx)
replaceKEEPFIRST(myy)
```

and for your work:

```
big$price.x <- replaceKEEPFIRST(big$price.x)
big$price.y <- replaceKEEPFIRST(big$price.y)
```

Comment: Perhaps it will help to mention that the OP would need to have the zoo package for this

Comment: @A_K `library(zoo)` is in the code.  @flodel, thanks for the clean

Comment: Glad it came in at the same time I posted the 1st comment! :-)

Comment: @flodel Great! I neeed to merge the data and time into one vector but besides that I think this will work. One question though for the na.locf function - if the first instance is in fact an NA in the vector, will those be deleted, left NA, ignored or will the first occurence that is not NA fill in the proceeding NAs ? When i read the description it only mentioned prioir NAs would be filled out. I appreciate the help. Thanks a lot

Comment: they get removed: `ss <- c(NA,4,2,3,NA);na.locf(ss)`
but from your question this did not arise, what would you like done with these occurences?

Comment: As I need the vectors to be of the same length they should not be removed. The first occurence should be used if NA appears prior to this. The function above will work for the rest of the data.

Comment: To clarify. There should be no NAs, if the first data point is an NA then it should use the first price point that is not NA to fill out those before it. For all the NAs after the first price point the na.locf will work, as it will use the prior price point to fill in the NAs. Thanks again

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will give it a try a little later when I have access to the data and post a response. Thanks!

Comment: I am running into a problem with the data input. The merge function seems to include much more than it should when it merges on 'time'. I am reading two csv files using the normal read.csv statement. I access the rows in the data frame with the $ sign append for instance $time. I believe that the merge statement isn't picking this up correctly and is producing an output that is longer than both price vectors combined, which it should not. Is there something that I am overlooking in the data input?

Comment: perhaps you need to read `?merge`, is there a column called `time` in each data.frame and are you specifying `by="time` in merge?

Comment: Both data frames contain the time column, and I am specifying the by = "time" in the merge statement. I believe it is in the merge that something is happening which shouldn't. I looked into the join option in the plyr package as well as some SQL based merges. The

Comment: perhaps you should use `dput(head(...))` on both your actual data sets and ask a new fresh question on your merge problem. I find it difficult to know whats going on without an example. as the code I gave works fine on what you provided

Comment: I asked a more detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225253/merging-vectors-from-data-frame